# Segfault when accessing nodes of binary search tree

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am implementing a simple binary search tree in C with the following structs:

```
typedef struct bstNode{
    double val;
    struct bstNode* left;
    struct bstNode* right; 
} Node;

typedef struct bsTree{
    Node* root;
    size_t size;
} BST;
```

where `BST* createTree(double val)` returns a binary search tree struct with the following routine:

```
BST* createTree(double val){
    Node* root = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    root->val = val;
    root->right = NULL;
    root->left = NULL;
    BST* t = malloc(sizeof(BST));
    if(t == NULL){
        free(root);
        free(t);
        return NULL;
    }
    t->root = root;
    t->size = 1;
    return t;
}
```

Additionally, I have implemented `int insert(BST* tree, double in)` that inserts a given value as a node into the binary search tree:

```
int insert(BST* tree, double in){
    if(tree->root == NULL)  return -1;
    Node* curr = tree->root;

    while(curr!=NULL){
        if(curr->val<=in){
            curr = curr->right;
        }else{
            curr = curr->left;
        }
    }

    curr = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(curr == NULL){
        printf("Could not create new node");
    }
    curr->val = in;
    curr->right = NULL;
    curr->left = NULL;
    tree->size = tree->size + 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Now if I test the implementation with the following code:

```
int main(){
    BST* tree = createTree(1.0);
    if(tree==NULL){
        printf("Tree could not be created");
        return -1;
    }

    insert(tree, 2.0);
    printf("%lf\n", tree->root->right->val);
    destroyTree(tree);

    return 0;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault even though I have successfully created `curr` inside the `insert()` function. I tried various things such as already malloc'ing the right and left nodes of root in advance (in the `createTree()` method), but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In the insert function you are malloc-ing a new node (curr), but you never link it to the rest of the tree.

Comment: @jmq May I ask why it isn't linked to the rest of the tree when we are traversing the tree? Curr is the child of some node in the tree, because curr = curr->right or curr->left.

Comment: You are traversing the tree, but you are throwing out the result.  I'm not exactly sure how you want to attach it to the tree. Right now after the while loop curr will be NULL.  The value of curr after the while loop doesn't matter since you are overwriting it anyway.

Comment: @jmq After reading the below answer I see what you mean. Curr is overwritten by malloc() and we have to link it to the parent. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newly created `Node` inside `insert` is not attached to your tree.

`curr` is local variable, and when you modify it by `curr = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node))` it just changes the value of this pointer, but none of nodes in tree will point to this value.

Easy way to fix this is to create temporary pointer which points "parent" of nodes, and add one bool variable which indicates to which node (left or right) of parent new child pointer should be assigned.

```
int insert(BST* tree, double in){
    if(tree->root == NULL)  return -1;
    Node* curr = tree->root;

    Node* parent = NULL;      // added
    bool addToRight = false;  // added
    while(curr!=NULL){
        parent = curr;
        if(curr->val<=in){
            curr = curr->right;
            addToRight = true; // added
        }else{
            curr = curr->left;
            addToRight = false; // added 
        }
    }

    curr = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(curr == NULL){
        printf("Could not create new node");
    }
    curr->val = in;
    curr->right = NULL;
    curr->left = NULL;

    if (addToRight)             // added
        parent->right = curr;
    else 
        parent->left = curr;

    tree->size = tree->size + 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Another solution is to use `Node**`. In this way you can store address of leaf (left or right) and set it to a value of pointer returned from `malloc`.

```
Node** t = NULL; // added
while(curr!=NULL){
    if(curr->val<=in){
        curr = curr->right;
        t = &(curr->right); // added
    }else{
        curr = curr->left;
        t = &(curr->left); // added
    }
}

curr = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
if(curr == NULL){
    printf("Could not create new node");
}
*t = curr; // added
curr->val = in;
curr->right = NULL;
curr->left = NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought that the parent node will still point to curr after I malloc it, but obviously this is not true.

Comment: If you have `Node* ptr` by `ptr = ...` you can set only pointee i.e. a value the pointer points to. But to change value of pointer itself you need to always use pointer to pointer - `Node** ptr`, so in `*ptr = ...` you change value of memory cell occupied by pointer - it is what you wanted to achive.